# Cómo saber si un método o propiedad está siendo sobreescrita

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Tengo una clase que solamente define algunas propiedades públicas pero que tiene una larga cadena de herencia.

```
public class AgencyPaginatedQuery : SortedPaginatedQuery
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
}

public class SortedPaginatedQuery : PaginatedQuery
{
    public string Sort { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
}


public class PaginatedQuery
{
    public int? Start { get; set; }
    public int? Size { get; set; }
}
```

La clase que estoy examinando es `AgencyPaginatedQuery` y estoy tratando de obtener los nombres de dichas propiedades usando LINQ y Reflection. Hasta ahora he sido capaz de obtener cuales de estas propiedades pertenecen a la clase en cuestión con una simple consulta

```
var type = typeof(AgencyPaginatedQuery);
var names = from prop in type.GetProperties()
            where prop.DeclaringType.Name == type.Name &&
                  prop.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property
            select prop.Name;
```

Esto me retorna

```
[0] = "Code" 
[1] = "Name" 
[2] = "Initials"
```

Pero ahora me falta filtrar de esa lista las propiedades que son sobreescritas para en caso que yo escriba

```
public class AgencyPaginatedQuery : SortedPaginatedQuery
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public override string Sort { get; set; }
}
```

esta última propiedad `Sort` no me aparezca en la lista.

¿Como puedo saber si la propiedad tiene un `override` usando mi consulta?

**PD:** Sé que debo marcar como virtual la propiedad en la clase base para que esto funcione.

Comment: Creo que en lugar de que `PaginatedQuery` y `SortedPaginatedQuery` sean clases deberían ser interfaces y así poder separarlos. Inclusive, sería una mejor idea si se pudiese aplicar un decorator sobre estas interfaces.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Necesito que sean clases porque esas clases pueden llegar a ser usadas directamente en caso que sólo necesite ordenar o usar paginación. Crear una interfaz no ayuda en ese sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paso una forma de checkearlo mediante `GetBaseDefinition()`

Usando el flag `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` ignoras los miembros heredados.

```
Type type = typeof(AgencyPaginatedQuery);

foreach ( var property in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)) {
    var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(false);
    if (getMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == getMethod) {
        Console.WriteLine(getMethod);
    }
}
```

si la propiedad está sobre-escrita el `MethodInfo` del *getter* será diferente al `MethodInfo` de `GetBaseDefinition()`

Podrías obtenerlo de esta manera:

```
var names = from prop 
              in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
             let getMethod = prop.GetGetMethod(false)
           where getMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == getMethod
          select prop.Name;
```

Como resultado obtengo:

> Code
>    Name
>    Initials

Comment: Me da el siguiente error `PropertyIfo` does not contain a definition for `GetBaseDefinition`

Comment: voy a intentar replicarlo y edito mi post.

Comment: Usar solamente `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` parece estropear los resultados ya que me retorna la lista vacía aunque elimine todos los demás filtros.

Comment: si tienes razón

Comment: agregando estos funciona : BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance

Comment: corregí el ejemplo

Comment: Perfecto, esa combinación de flags es la correcta. Creo que agregando `let getMethod = prop.GetGetMethod(false) where getMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == getMethod` queda más legible

Comment: Listo, lo corregí para que quede mas legible.